# How to use jQuery to change attribute of all elements in a group except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following code that shows a light box for my image gallery. There are three images and I need to allow users to click on any of the images to see the gallery in a lightbox. The issue is that when I click on one image it does not show the selected image rather shows the first image in the list / or last image that user has seen last time that opened the lightbox. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwugprj3/3/)

I have a carousel based on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ in my lightbox, so I need to change the order of the carousel. I noticed the plugin generates `tabindex` attribute so I am trying to change that to `0 for selected image` and `-1 for all other images` but the code does not work. I included a demo but for some reasons it does not work at all. Please use following code while I am trying to solve the issue with JSFiddle.

To solve the issue with attributes, I had a look at these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669163/jquery-select-all-elements-except-one-with-specific-child-with-specific-attribu), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211222/jquery-check-if-attr-value), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912263/jquery-how-to-set-parent-attribute) but could not figure out how to use it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>slick - the last carousel you'll ever need</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/style.css">


  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
#cover-page {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 1001;
  visibility:hidden;
}
#black-cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#close{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
      visibility:inherit;
}
.slick-slider {
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 9%;
}
.slick-slider {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    visibility:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slick-slide img {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.slick-next {
  right: -66px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -66px;
}

#lightboxCloseBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;

}

.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active{
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 999;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="black-cover"></div>
        <div id="cover-page">
       <div id="close"><a id="lightboxCloseBtn" href="#" onclick="closeBtn();">X</a></div>
        <h2 id="lightboxHeader">Images</h2>
        <div class="slider fade">
        <div class="lightbox-image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-"/></div>
          <div class="lightbox-image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY"/></div>
           <div class="lightbox-image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ"/></div>

        </div>
        </div>


        <a onclick="showLightBox('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-');" href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-"/></a>
        <a onclick="showLightBox('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY');" href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY"/></a>
         <a onclick="showLightBox('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ');" href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ"/></a>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/js/prism.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showLightBox(address){
            $("#black-cover").css("visibility","visible");
            $("#cover-page").css("visibility","visible");
            $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","visible");
            if($('.lightbox-image.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > img').attr('src') != address) {
              alert("here 2");
    $('.lightbox-image.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > img').parent().attr('tabindex','-1');

        }
        if($('.lightbox-image.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > img').attr('src') == address) {
              alert("here 1");
    $('.lightbox-image.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > img').parent().attr('tabindex','0');

        } 
      }

        function closeBtn(){
            $("#black-cover").css("visibility","hidden");
            $("#cover-page").css("visibility","hidden");
            $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","hidden");

}

        var disqus_shortname = 'slickcarousel';

        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Following is the code that plugin generates:

```
<div id="cover-page" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div id="close">
        <a onclick="closeBtn();" href="#" id="lightboxCloseBtn">X</a>
    </div>
    <h2 id="lightboxHeader">Images</h2>
    <div class="slider fade slick-initialized slick-slider" role="toolbar"
        style="visibility: visible;">
        <button role="button" aria-label="Previous"
            class="slick-prev slick-arrow" data-role="none" type="button"
            style="display: block;">Previous</button>
        <div class="slick-list draggable" aria-live="polite">
            <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 3735px;"
                role="listbox">
                <div class="lightbox-image slick-slide slick-current slick-active"
                    data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false"
                    style="width: 1245px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;"
                    tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00">
                    <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-">
                </div>
                <div class="lightbox-image slick-slide" data-slick-index="1"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    style="width: 1245px; position: relative; left: -1245px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;"
                    tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide01">
                    <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY">
                </div>
                <div class="lightbox-image slick-slide" data-slick-index="2"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    style="width: 1245px; position: relative; left: -2490px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;"
                    tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide02">
                    <img
                        src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <button role="button" aria-label="Next" class="slick-next slick-arrow"
            data-role="none" type="button" style="display: block;">Next</button>
        <ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;" role="tablist">
            <li class="slick-active" aria-hidden="false" role="presentation"
                aria-selected="true" aria-controls="navigation00" id="slick-slide00"><button
                    tabindex="0" aria-required="false" role="button" data-role="none"
                    type="button">1</button></li>
            <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false"
                aria-controls="navigation01" id="slick-slide01"><button
                    tabindex="0" aria-required="false" role="button" data-role="none"
                    type="button">2</button></li>
            <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false"
                aria-controls="navigation02" id="slick-slide02"><button
                    tabindex="0" aria-required="false" role="button" data-role="none"
                    type="button">3</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example please?

Comment: @joshhunt I pasted the code in JSFiddle but it does not work. I am working on it. What other changes do you want me to make?

Comment: The `tabindex` attribute begins at 1, so 0 and -1 are equally useless.  Not actually sure what you want to do with the `tabindex` here...

Comment: @Jack maybe instead of using your original code try creating a basic demo demonstrating what you want to do, this might also help you find the solution. @Deryck `tabindex` 0 and -1 do indeed have purposes. E.g. you can assign 0 to a `<div>` to make it tabbable (without changing the tabbing priority) and you assign -1 to a `<button>` to make it untabbable.

Comment: @Deryck all I need to do is that once user selects an image the selected image be shown in the lightbox.

Comment: @joshhunt oh very interesting didn't think about that.  thanks for that :)

Comment: What lightbox plugin are you using?

Comment: @joshhunt the main issue is that I have a carousel based on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ in my lightbox, so I need to change the order of the carousel.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/gxG87/ ?

Comment: I recommend on reading: [How to ask a **good** question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @099 I rephrased it thanks.

Comment: There is a dedicated parameter you can use here... see in my answer. You don't need to "hack" it yourself and play with the tabindex attribute at all...

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that your Javascript is set to load `onload`, it works fine if you wrap it in the head (and add jQuery in the demo): http://jsfiddle.net/zwugprj3/3/

This happens, because of a different scope of the scripts, so `onclick="..."` doesn't have access to your function.

Generally, stop using the `onclick` attribute!

Use [`addEventHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. You can still put the URL (your parameter) in your HTML by using a data attribute like: `<img src="/small.png" data-large-src="/large.png">`.

**Update:** Read til the end of Slick's documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/zwugprj3/22/, there's actually a method you should use to change the slide. Changing internal details of a library directly is almost never a good idea....

Comment: I tried the demo you provided, it shows the lightbox but did not solve the issue, the issue is that images are listed from 0-1-2, if you click on either 1 or 2 the lightbox still shows image with id 0.

Comment: @Jack: I added a actual working solution... it was just having a look at the documentation, this would have really been your job.

Comment: Appreciate that, I was sick past few days. Will have a look at your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
HTML CODE:

<a onclick="showLightBox(0);" href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-"/></a>
    <a onclick="showLightBox(1);" href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY"/></a>
     <a onclick="showLightBox(2);" href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ"/></a>



JS CODE:

  function showLightBox(idx){
        $("#black-cover").css("visibility","visible");
        $("#cover-page").css("visibility","visible");
        $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","visible");
        $('.slick-dots li button').eq(idx).trigger('click');

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

HTML

```
<div id="black-cover" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="cover-page" style="display:none;">
        <div id="close">
            <a id="lightboxCloseBtn" href="#" onclick="closeBtn();">X</a>
        </div>
        <h2 id="lightboxHeader">Images</h2>
        <div class="your-class">
            <div>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="img" data-value="0"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRu3mvhWwEfOLKJrXAXS4qATDZNtx-l04Vhwi3oXr_62Mz5lEZ-"/></a>

<a href="#" class="img" data-value="1"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKGgx0Le2Rwg7-XSWS_EeuGeebpL-PGabrEm9hFLk2llz1MnQY"/></a>

<a href="#" class="img" data-value="2"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMKybiZVNTHLJXR5bukMNmKv3lCHGlkP2muKAfGn0u6VceubqMyQ"/></a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.img').click(function () {
        var CurrentImg = $(this).attr('data-value')
        $("#black-cover").show()
        $("#cover-page").show()
        $('.your-class').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            initialSlide: CurrentImg
        });
    })
})

function closeBtn() {
    $("#black-cover").hide()
    $("#cover-page").hide()
    $('.your-class').slick('unslick');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/dwof2qeh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a specific parameter called `initialSlide` (default:0) you can use just for that. Just pass the index of the image that was clicked and you're all set.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), the parameter `initial slide` can only be used when initiating the carousel, so as a workaround if you want to decide which image should be focused only when it's clicked, you can initiate the carousel when one of your images is clicked, and when the user closes the carousel, you should destroy it using the `unslick`parameter like so:

`$('.your-slider').slick('unslick');`

And then if he clicks on some other image, just re-initiate the carousel with the correct `initialSlide` parameter.

Look at the documentation: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: It seems like that is used for initialization not runtime changes, if not how to change it do you have a clue? I am not sure what to do.

Comment: If this is the case, you can just initialise the plugin only when an image is clicked, and dispose the carousel immediately after that. Do it again for every additional click...

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks the image you should construct the slick slider with the relevant image. You can do so by injecting the image's index to a function holding the slick slider constructor:

```
function startSlider (index) {
  // put here all the css visibility you did
  $('.your-sliders-class').slick({
    initialSlide: index      // the first slide's index is 0, second is 1...
  })
}
```

So your onclick function will look like:

for the first image - `onclick="startSlider(0)"`

for the second image - `onclick="startSlider(1)"`

and so on...

In addition, you should destroy the slider when user closes the lightbox, so the next time he clicks an image the lightbox will construct with the right initial slide:

```
function closeBtn(){
   $("#black-cover").css("visibility","hidden");
   $("#cover-page").css("visibility","hidden");
   $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","hidden");
   $('.your-sliders-class').slick('unslick');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to change the order will not work due to the way the slider is implemented.  I have solved the inherent problem by displaying the image you clicked on by default.

```
  function showLightBox(address){
            $("#black-cover").css("visibility","visible");
            $("#cover-page").css("visibility","visible");
            $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","visible");
            //slick-dots
            var index = $('.lightbox-image.slick-slide > img[src="' + address + '"]').parent().index();
            $('ul.slick-dots > li').eq(index).find('button').click();
      }

        function closeBtn(){
            $("#black-cover").css("visibility","hidden");
            $("#cover-page").css("visibility","hidden");
            $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","hidden");

}
```

^^ That is the modified javascript from your jsFiddle
My jsFiddle can be viewed here http://jsfiddle.net/q6t8v3zf/1/

Answer (score 0):

looking the Github of slick, i see many issues with the same problem [1](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/396) , [2](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/755) ....
initialSlide must work but in this issues you can see many examples of workarrounds to solve the problem.This configuration of slick must work.

```
 $('.my-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        initialSlide: 2
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According your question I feel that you want to manually handle the situation, by changing the index for all the other images to -1 and then set the current selected one, is that correcT? if thats the case let me know I will help you fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of experimenting with the `tabindex` attribute, I would instruct the Slick to start showing the images with the selected slide. There is a method called [slickGoTo(..)](https://www.javascripting.com/view/slick) that can be used to do so:

> **slickGoTo( index : int, dontAnimate : bool)** Goes to slide by index,
>   skipping animation if second parameter is set to true

Thus your function would look like:

```
function showLightBox(address){
    $("#black-cover").css("visibility","visible");
    $("#cover-page").css("visibility","visible");
    $(".slick-slider").css("visibility","visible");

    // find the image with the same address
    var index = 0;
    var notFound = true;

    $('.lightbox-image > img').each( function() {
      var sameAddress = $(this).attr('src') == address ;
      if (notFound && !sameAddress) index++;
      else notFound = false;
    });

    // Set initial slide
    $('.slick-slider').slick('slickGoTo', index, true);
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwugprj3/8/)

Comment: This sets the Slick option, so you don't have to destroy and create the whole carousel on every click (as suggested in other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Two points. 
(1) tabIndex is used to set the tab sequence, generally in a form, so that the tab key knows how to navigate from element to element. It does not move a DOM element automatically to the foreground. What you're trying to accomplish is to have the generated carousel 'jump' to the image selected from the main page. 
(2) Since you're using slick, you want to use the "initialSlide" parameter on load to tell slick which (of your three) slides to start with. 
From their documentation, you would set this when you activate a slide by executing a function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
  initialSlide: 1
  });
});
```